# Sequlize How to store array of strings in SQLite table column

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I need to store array of strings in column and make queries by this column. I tried to use JSON data type of column but i need to make [Op.like] query by this json column. Example:

```
{
  actors: {
    [Op.like]: `%${actor}%`,
  },
},
```

But it does not work.

Comment: 1) Could you describe how it does not work? 2) Arrays are awkward in SQL. Use a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) instead. 3) Could you show us your schema?

Comment: const Movies = sequelize.define(
  MOVIES,
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    year: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    format: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    actors: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, @Schwern

Comment: @Schwern i need to store array names of actors in actors column

Comment: You can look at JSON functions in Sqlite maybe one of them (maybe a function that transforms a JSON array into a recordset) would be helpful

Comment: @Matviy "*But it does not work.*" Would you show us how it does not work, please?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* store an array of actors in the movies table, but this is not an efficient way to store lists in SQL.

Instead, use a [many-to-many relationship](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#many-to-many-relationships). This means having a separate actors table, and a table to link actors to movies.

```
const Movies = sequelize.define(
   MOVIES,
   # Add columns as normal, but no actors column.
);

const Actors = sequelize.define(
  ACTORS,
  # Add columns as normal.
);

Movies.belongsToMany(Actors);
Actors.belongsToMany(Movies);
```

And then query a movie actors with `include`.

```
const movie = await Movies.findOne({
  where: { title: "Bad Taste" },
  include: Actors,
});

# and now work with movie.actors
```

This is faster, and more flexible. Actors can appear in many movies without having to duplicate their data, and you can store as much data as you want for an actor. SQL will enforce that every actor for every movie actually exists.

Comment: And how to create record in ActorsMovies table when i create new Movies with this request body:
`
{
    "title": "Dream",
    "year": 2022,
    "format": "DVD",
    "actors": [
        "Jared Leto",
        "Kei Cenat"
    ]
}
`
@Schwern

Comment: @Matviy 1) [findOrCreate](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findorcreate) the Actors 2) Create the Movie. 3) Add the list of actors to the movie: `movie.addActors(actors)`. See https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#foobelongstomanybar--through-baz-

Comment: I need to use forEach loop to make 1) findOrCreate the Actors? How it must look like? 
Like this? 
await actors.forEach((actor) =>
        Actors.findOrCreate({
          where: { name: actor },
        })
      );

Comment: or what u mean ?

Comment: @Matviy Like that, but since you need the resulting Actor models, you probably want to use a map.